# Can destructiveChanges.xml be invoked directly from the Force.com IDE without Ant?

Tags: deployment, ide, destructivechanges.xml

In a couple of old projects we have an Ant target setup to run a deploy with a [destructiveChanges.xml](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Propagating_Destructive_Changes) file specified.

AFAIK the Force.com IDE "Deploy to Server..." takes no notice of this - Ant has to be used. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer "no" here https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/19 (where the Force.com IDE is open sourced).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the Developer Workbench to deploy destructive changes - as you said, the Force.com IDE cannot be used for these.

https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: Thanks Davin - not looking for an alternatives though just conformation that the Foce.com IDE doesn't support it.

Comment: Ah right, fair enough. In that case I guess you have your answer, although finding documentation which states that the IDE doesn't support it may be tough.